# Handwriting recognition engine for web application

Tags: php

I am developing web application  using PHP.Client `wants to integrate the hand writing recognition engine to our application(Like whatever you written it needs to convert into text format).I don't have any idea on this`.Could you please give some suggestion and ideas on how to integrate the engine to PHP.
P.S:Open source is preferable.If not available no problem on the money constraint.

Comment: You're kidding, right? good OCR software is expensive, and only works when comparing existing, known fonts, with a regular pattern, where the differences between letters is as small as it can get. Handwriting? Maybe in a few years. For PHP? That's like writing a space shuttle launch program in Lolcode.

Comment: You may be able to tap into a handwriting recognition library/API on system level using  `exec()` or a web service. There is no native PHP solution for this, and probably never will be (it's too far outside its scope).

Comment: Alexander: So I guess existing handwriting recognition software actually doesn't work? Also Lolcode is perfectly suitable for space industry grade applications, as long as it can get compiled to machine code. :P

Comment: @Alexander it's absolutely not impossible. See libraries like http://playground.sun.com/pub/multimedia/handwriting/hre.html

Comment: @vinoth you need to add some details about your server environment

Comment: @Pekka, FYI, PHP can interoperate in many forms with other software. You can write a PHP extension in C++, or use the COM in Windows, or even use .NET assemblies.

Comment: @Pekka, software which can recognize some characters may exist. CAPTCHAS are being broken. But that software is slow, and doesn't work for actual handwriting, where an r can be written in tens of absolutely different ways (some even I, a human, can't recognize). It's rarely actually usable. @Mchl, it would just look funny, weigh a lot, and need a lot of time to write it.

Comment: @Alexander go to the nearest computer store and try out Windows 7 on a Tablet PC. It manages to even recognize *my* handwriting with a 95% success rate - and that means something! :P There are decent solutions for this nowadays. Not perfect, but decent

Comment: @Pekka Now I am working locally using Xampp and we already integrate the scanner application with COM object.SO server may be preferably windows server.

Comment: @Pekka, I should see it on my handwriting :). 95% is a good rate, no doubt, but it's far from being able to use it in practice. It would be faster and cheaper to hire a typist, rather than a corrector that would try to understand what the very expensive computer with expensive software saw when he wrote "A shinny man". I still strongly believe that this technology is too young for practice, and it will be a few years (2,5,10?) until it's at the level OCR is today.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer to your question, but Windows XP Tablet, Vista and 7 have this already built in like so:

[image]

these controls will pop up when the user taps an input field.

They are bound to be superior to whatever API or library you manage to come up with, because they are trained to their "master's" handwriting, and manage to provide specific input components that are impossible to implement in a web site.

Maybe having clients use this technology can solve part of your problem without any effort on your end - it really depends on the nature of the project.

Also, I found this: [Server-side handwriting recognition in Windows 2008 server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee318410(VS.85).aspx) - maybe you can tap into that through COM, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution but I doubt its PHP, its Ruby i believe:

Look here to see if this gets you closer to your goal: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/

Source is available on GitHub: http://github.com/kirel/detexify

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander says - no such software exists (if you could write such a thing then you could retire on the royalties!)

Do you really need handwriting recognition or do you just need to capture an image of what the user writes? The latter is relatively trivial.

C.

Comment: I dont need an image.I need it in a text  format.I already mentioned in my question

Comment: Let me know when you've written it - if it works I'll buy shares in your company!